# How to update a field based on its current value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Is it possible to get the current value of a field, use it as a variable in a calculation, then update the field based on the result?

For example the record with the ID "1" in table1 has a value of "2"

```
SELECT table1
WHERE ID = "1"
SET RESULT to CurrentID
RESULT = CurrentID + 1;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will set the `result` column to the value of the `CurrentID` column (plus 1) of the same row, for any row that has an `ID` column that equals "1":

```
UPDATE table1
SET result = CurrentID + 1
WHERE ID = "1"
```

Answer (score 7):

You might try

```
Update table1 set ID = ID+1 where ID = 1
```

Comment: Why would he not just do `SET ID=2 WHERE ID=1`?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, if he's only doing one `ID` at a time, then he can set an explicit value and bypass the calculation

Comment: @JNK: No I'm not doing one value at a time, my example code was pretty poor -- wasn't even sure if this was possible so I was trying to keep the code as simple as possible. John K. code appears to work, though I'm not able to get Oded's to work.

Comment: Right... I've been looking back at the question.  Not quite sure why he asked it like that, but I suppose there's more that he'd like to do based on the question...I added on the where clause based on his example.