# FusionTables SQL: Altering the value of a column

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

Let's say I have a column called "points", and I want to update "points" with the current value of points + X (where X is any number)

For Example

```
UPDATE tablename SET points=points+30 WHERE userID=1
```

I have tried the following:

- points = points + 30
- points += 30
- points = tablename.points + 30

I just keep getting error:

> Error 2601: Fusion tables returned an error. (I'm querying the fusion table from within my app) The response was: 400 Bad Request Invalid query: Parse error near 'points'

Is there a way to SELECT the current value of points, then UPDATE points=points+x?

EDIT:
The question is the same as the one suggested, but it did not solve my problem. So..... what should I do? I know people come in here and edit stuff I've written, so do what you want with this thread, because you're going to anyway.

Comment: Your code is fine. You have another problem with your code.

Comment: "I just keep getting errors" - what/where are these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a field based on its current value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668195/how-to-update-a-field-based-on-its-current-value-in-mysql)

Comment: what is the datatype of points? If it is a char type of some sort then you will have a typecasting issue. If that is the case then look up `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Comment: Please copy the error your database returned into your question.

Comment: Without the error message, one cannot tell where you are going wrong. Because this SQL query looks perfectly fine and it should work.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your example. There must be something else about the context you haven't shown resulting in a problem. As others have said, show exactly what you tried and show the corresponding error.

Comment: Error 2601: Fusion tables returned an error.

(I'm querying the fusion table from within my app)

The response was: 400 Bad Request Invalid query: Parse error near 'points'

Seems like a pretty straight forward query to me.
Seems like it SHOULD work.
That's why I'm stumped.

THERE LITERALLY IS NOTHING ELSE TO SHOW.
Everyone is saying "show the blah blah blah"

But it's like if you have a blank page.
The connection works.
I can select data.
I can update data.
I can delete data.
I can add data.

But when I attempt to update in this manner.. error.

Comment: So you are using google fusion tables?

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Fusion Tables, and I'm thinking that might be the problem. It could be that my query isn't supported by the fusion table

Answer (score 1):

FusionTables does not support math in its SQL. You'll need to use a query to get the current value, perform the necessary math outside of SQL, and then call [UPDATE](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#updateRow) with the new value.

Example (in Python):

```
getCurrent = "SELECT ROWID, points from <tableid> WHERE userID = 1"
resp = FusionTables.query().sqlGet(sql=getCurrent, ...).execute()
rowid = resp['rows'][0]
newPoints = str(int(resp['rows'][1]) + 30)
updatePoints = "UPDATE <tableid> SET points = " + newPoints + " WHERE ROWID = " + rowid
resp = FusionTables.query().sql(sql=updatePoints, ...).execute()
```

You can only update one row at a time, so if you have many operations to perform it may be simpler / cheaper / faster to stage the changes until you have a certain number to do, then use `replaceRows` for a bulk update (i.e. download all data, make the needed changes to the various rows, then re-upload). There are extra steps if your dataset is larger than 10 MB, but it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My code may be able to help someone facing this issue using Java.

I needed to update information in rows of a fusion table in many different ways that were unsupported by fusion tables implementation of SQL. I wrote a java program to help me do my updates. (I'm trying to clean up my data in my fusion table.) I also needed to find a nearby large city / state and update fields in rows with this information. Anyway, you can see the entire program on github.

The entire project directory is found on github here: https://github.com/gjkendall/FusionTableModifyJava

The code of interest is in FusionTableSample.java based on Google/Christian Junks example program of how to create, access and modify fusion tables in java. I'm new a java so it might not be the best code.

You will see a lot of commented code where I did different SQL searches for different things I needed to modify. These are there so I can reference them for future searches.

The program first does a SQL search for the rows I want to modify and puts those rows into an array(mylist). The project goes through the array mylist one row at a time, makes it's modifications (currently I needed to access geonames to get city and state info based on locations in my table) and then updates the row with a fusion table SQL call.

The routine that does the updates row by row is "updateRows" shown here:

```
private static void updateRows(String tableId) throws IOException {
    // IOException needed  ParseException
    count = 1;
    mylist.forEach((myRow) -> {
        try {
            // modify fields in table...
            //newAreaName = kt.firstpart(myRow.get(NOTES).toString()); //get Notes first sentence
            //newAreaName = newAreaName.replace("'", "''");
            //newAreaName += " X01";
            //String state = getStateFrmLoc(myRow.get(LOCATION).toString());
            //String state = "MX-BCS";
            float km;
            if ( "AK,MT,NV".contains(myRow.get(STATE).toString()) ) {
                km = 180f; // 111.85 miles
            } else {
                km = 80.5f;  // 50 miles
            }

            BigCity big = new BigCity(myRow.get(LOCATION).toString(), km);
            String cityState = big.cityName +", "+big.state;

            if (big.population < 10000f) {
                System.out.println("Skip for low population :"+myRow.get(NUMBER));
            } else {

                sqlupdate = "UPDATE " + tableId + " " +
                        "SET 'City (nearest)' = '" + cityState + "' " +
                        ",'Codes' = '" + myRow.get(CODES).toString() + ",#U1' " +
                        "WHERE ROWID = " + myRow.get(ROW_ID);
                System.out.println("[" + count + "]" + myRow.get(NUMBER) + ": " + sqlupdate);

                // do the update...
                if (!mtest) {  // if testing then don't update
                    sql_doupdate(sqlupdate);
                }
                count++;
                if ((count % 30) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("waiting 60 seconds");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60); //Fusion Tables allows 30 updates then must wait 1 minute.
                }
            }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using MySQL you must disable safe update propriety with the following commande `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

You can use the CONCAT() Function, here MySQL example :

SELECT example :

```
SELECT point, CONCAT(point, ' ', id)
FROM points_table;
```

UPDATE example :

```
UPDATE points_table 
SET point = CONCAT(point, ' ', id);
```

Reference : [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: OP does not state he uses MySQL. Also he does not need safe query settings since he uses where clause.

Comment: You can't use `concat` to add numbers.